# Duda Threads en C#

Tags: c#, .net, hilos, consola

Buenos días estoy estudiando C# y me he encontrado con la necesidad de hacer que mi programa haga una pausa, hasta que pasen x segundos o hasta que el mismo usuario genere un evento. He intentado trasladar mis conocimientos de threads de java a C# pero no termina de funcionar correctamente.
Mi pregunta es: ¿se puede hacer una pausa en el programa y que se genere un evento bien si el usuario ha realizado una acción o bien cuando han pasado x segundos?
PD: estoy trabajando realizando una aplicación de consola en .NET
PD2: gracias de antemano.

Comment: qué versión del framework usas? y de visual studio.

Comment: De Visual Studio la 15.8.4 y de .NET la 4.7.03

Comment: No creo que necesites usar threading para eso. Usa un timer con una variable que haga de flag, y que se active cuando se dispare el timer o cuando el usuario realice la accion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses la clase Timer de c#. 
Te paso un ejemplo de como funciona :

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer crono;

    private static void SetTimer(double tiempo)

            {
    //EL TIEMPO LO MULTIPLICO POR 1000 PARA QUE ESTE EN SEGUNDOS.

                crono = new System.Timers.Timer(tiempo*1000);
                crono.AutoReset = false;
                crono.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
                crono.Enabled = true;
            }

            private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
//AQUI CODIFICAS EL EVENTO QUE QUIERES QUE SE EJECUTE CUANDO PASEN LOS SEGUNDOS
            }
        }
```

Para iniciar el timer llama en tu programa a `SetTimer(tiempo);`

Y para detenerlo

```
crono.Stop();
crono.Dispose();
```